# Website cannot establish connection to the sql on server

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

The website runs perfectly fine on my local computer with connection string containing database information of already hosted server. but when i upload the website on the server i get this error. the main page of the website is loading but the other features that has sql connection accessibility are not.

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll
>   from the location specified in the registry. Verify that the Local
>   Database Runtime feature of SQL Server Express is properly
>   installed.)]

My local default connection string is

```
 <add name="defaultconnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=aspnet-fuzzzz-20160406102902;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-fuzzzz-20160406102902.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Apart from that i have the entity framework model connection string that contains sql authentication of a remote server that contains data..

Revised and additional information -
my filter looks like this could it be the server is by default taking my default connection string instead of my entity framework connection string

```
 public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new UsersContext())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
             }
             }
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to configure your credentials properly.

Comment: i am really not an expert in network just a rookie developer so any advice on expanding your explanation will be much appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci

Comment: Please use the above link to resolve your issue.